# Adding count from another table to variable with method chain

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq, method-chaining

I have a table of posts, and a table of likes. All likes for a post id have to be counted in order to get the total likes for each post. Currently I do this by looping through all the posts which is very inefficient, but I cannot find the correct way to do this in a single database call.

```
List<Post> posts = await db.Posts.OrderByDescending(c => c.DateCreated)
                .ToListAsync();

foreach (Post post in posts)
{
      post.TotalLikes = await db.Likes.Where(d => d.PostID == post.ID).CountAsync();
}
```

Comment: Hint: join between Posts and Likes on Post.Id = Like.PostId.

Comment: Do you have set it as a navigation property in Post class?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I understand that part, but adding the count of likes to post.TotalLikes is what puzzles me.

Here's the join i've made:

`.Join(db.Likes, p => p.ID, pc => pc.PostID, (p, pc) => new { p, pc })`

Comment: @PrateekPandey it would be the easiest for me. Do you have an alternative?

Comment: I can easily do it in SQL, I've never done it in linq, though.... sorry, but I don't think I can help more.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Can you show me the SQL way?

Comment: one way to do it in sql would be to use a subquery: `select *, (select count(*) as from likes where post_id = p.Id) from posts p`. It can also be done with a join...

Comment: it's a simple join either by linq or make a stored procedure for that if you want to keep it out of the code

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
var posts = Posts.OrderByDescending(c => c.DateCreated)
                .Select(post => new { post, TotalLikes = Likes.Where(d => d.PostID == post.ID).Count()})
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
var query = from post in context.Posts
            let likes = from like in context.Likes
                        where like.PostId == post.Id
                        select like
            select new
            {
                PostId = post.Id,
                TotalLikes = likes.Count()
            };
```